# Joomla jos_session table crash

Tags: mysql, joomla

I recently got the following error

```
DB function failed with error number 145
'TABLE\ jos_session' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
SQL=SELECT session_id FROM jos_session WHERE session_id ....
```

This was accompanied by my site crashing. I fixed it by truncating the table

```
truncate table jos_session
```

It can also be fixed by repairing the table

```
repair table jos_session
```

My question is, how can we prevent this table from crashing to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several reasons this could have happened, so check the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/corrupted-myisam-tables.html) to see what might have happened in your case. We use SQLyog/monYog to monitor our databases and make sure nothing out of the ordinary in happening that might trigger such an error.   Bottom line - you'll have to do some digging to see what might cause it to happen again.

Answer (score 1):

From the information MySQL gives you, it's impossible to be sure, but the most common cause of a table crashing is running out of memory. I'd suggest upgrading your hardware.